# Paperclip image not uploads with faker gem data in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, faker

I'm trying to upload fake image data using faker gem, but I am seeing this error:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for "https://robohash.org/app/assets/image.jpg.png?size=300x300&set=set1"
```

in db/seed.rb

```
5.times do 
    Image.create([{
        filename:Faker::Food.dish,
        title:Faker::Food.dish,
        item_image:Faker::Avatar.image('app/assets/image.jpg')
                }])
        end
```

in db/image.rb

```
    class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
      def change
        create_table :images do |t|
          t.string :title
          t.string :filename
          t.timestamps

        end
      end

    end
```

in db/add_attachment_item_image_to_images.rb (paperclip gem migration file)

```
class AddAttachmentItemImageToImages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def self.up
    change_table :images do |t|
      t.attachment :item_image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :images, :item_image
  end
end
```

Comment: is  `multipart: true`  set in your form?

Comment: @nileshkumar lol, he is not creating it from form, it must be test data.

Comment: @ray: oh I see now  :)

Comment: Try with `Faker::Avatar.image('image.jpg')` or `Faker::Avatar.image("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/image.jpg")`

Comment: hi ray,it not working.same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with,

```
Faker::Avatar.image('image.jpg')
```

Your image must be in `app/assets/images`

or try following,

```
File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "app/assets/images/image.jpg"))
```

Comment: 20.times do
    Image.create(
     item_image: Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/food_image1.jpg").open,
     filename: "food",
     title: "food"
    )
             end  it tryed this way it work,but it store only one img all time.

Comment: If you have 20 images then you can do like, `20.times do |n|; Image.create( item_image: Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/food_image#{n}.jpg").open, filename: "food", title: "food" )`

Answer (score 0):

if FactoryGirl is your next option, you can use as follows in `spec/factories.rb`:

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :picture do 
      original_filename "test.jpg"
      file { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.to_s + '/spec/fixtures/files/test.jpg', 'img/jpeg') }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Faker::Avatar.image('app/assets/image.jpg')` returns a `String` with url to image placeholder (`"https://robohash.org/app/assets/image.jpg.png?size=300x300&set=set1"`), but Paperclip expects a file or IO there.

So you should pass something like `File.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'avatar.jpg'))` (and place some image at that path)

Answer (score 0):

it work

```
 20.times do
    Image.create(
     item_image: Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/image.jpg").open,
     filename: "Whole Wheat Pasta in Mushroom Sauce",
     title: "pasta"
                )
     end
```